# Tabbed Pages in React Does not allow me switch between tabs

Tags: html, reactjs

I am trying to make tabs in a react application in which there should be tab A and tab B.
I am doing this in React JS. How do i go about this?

My code is looking like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Dashboard.css';
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
import logo2 from './logo2.svg';
import clock from './clock.svg';

const Estimates = () => {

    function openPage(pageName,elmnt){
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");

        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
          }

        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
        }

        document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";
    }

    return (
        <div className="dashboardHome">
            <div className="SideBar">
                <div className="logo">
                    <img src={logo2} className="dashlogo" alt="logo" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="headerArea">
                <div>
                    <p><img src={clock} className="clock" alt="clock" /><font className="headerAreaDir"><h4>Estimating</h4></font></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="dataArea">
                <div>
                    <input type="text" placeholder=" &#xF002;  Search customers by name" className="searchBox" /> &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<p className="SearchFilterClass">Filter by: &nbsp; <select className="MySelector">
                        <option>7 Days</option>
                        <option>14 Days</option>
                        <option>21 Days</option>
                    </select></p>
                </div>

                &nbsp;&nbsp;<button className="estimates_area" onClick={openPage('upcoming_estimates',this)}>Upcoming Estimates</button>&nbsp;
                <button onClick={openPage('estimates_sent',this)}>Estimates Sent</button>
                <div className="estimates_area">
                <div>
                    <div id="upcoming_estimates" className="">
                        <h2>upcoming Estimates</h2>
                        <p>This area is for upcoming estimates</p>
                    </div>

                    <div id="estimates_sent" className="">
                    <h2>Sent Estimates</h2>
                        <p>This area is for Sent Estimates</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )

}

export default Estimates;
```

How do i make this into tabbed pages? Please I need some form of assistance here. I want something like this for instance, I click upcoming_estimates, it shows `upcoming_estimates` div, and the later. just need some clarification here

**Edits**

The main code is Looking like this now :

```
import React from 'react';
import './Dashboard.css';
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
import logo2 from './logo2.svg';
import clock from './clock.svg';

const Estimates = () => {

    function UpcomingEstimates(){
        return(
          <div id="upcoming_estimates" className="">
                <h2>upcoming Estimates</h2>
                <p>This area is for upcoming estimates</p>
          </div>
        )
      } 

      function EstimatesSent(){
        return(
          <div id="estimates_sent" className="">
              <h2>Sent Estimates</h2>
              <p>This area is for Sent Estimates</p>
          </div>
        )
      }

    return (
        <div className="dashboardHome">
            <div className="SideBar">
                <div className="logo">
                    <img src={logo2} className="dashlogo" alt="logo" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="headerArea">
                <div>
                    <p><img src={clock} className="clock" alt="clock" /><font className="headerAreaDir"><h4>Estimating</h4></font></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="dataArea">
                <div>
                    <input type="text" placeholder=" &#xF002;  Search customers by name" className="searchBox" /> &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<p className="SearchFilterClass">Filter by: &nbsp; <select className="MySelector">
                        <option>7 Days</option>
                        <option>14 Days</option>
                        <option>21 Days</option>
                    </select></p>
                </div>
                <div className="estimates_area">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;<button  href="/UpcomingEstimates" >Upcoming Estimates</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <button  href="/EstimatesSent">Estimates Sent</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )

}

export default Estimates;
```

Then App.Js is looking like this

```
import HomePage from './HomePage';
import Register from './Register';
import Dashboard from './DashBoard';
import { BrowserRouter, Route,Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Estimates from './Estimates';
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route path = '/' component={HomePage} exact/>
            <Route path = '/register' component={Register} />
            <Route path = '/estimates-home' component={Estimates} />
            <Route path = '/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />


            <Route path="/UpcomingEstimates" component={(props) => ( <UpcomingEstimates /> )} />
            <Route path="/estimatesSent" component={(props) => ( <EstimatesSent /> )} />   
        </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: implement react-router-dom with Switch and Route components

Comment: @AshishKamble, that is in my App.js can it solve this in this case?

Answer (score 0):

This way it will work, modify button with `href` to hit urls, which will call `Route`, separate out the `div` code into components, and render them

```
<button className="estimates_area" href="/UpcomingEstimates" >Upcoming Estimates</button>
<button onClick={} href="/estimatesSent">Estimates Sent</button>
```

You might want to change `href` url to,

```
<button className="estimates_area" href="/estimates-home/UpcomingEstimates" >Upcoming Estimates</button>
<button onClick={} href="/estimates-home/estimatesSent">Estimates Sent</button>
```

This is separate file, `UpcomingEstimates.js`

```
function UpcomingEstimates(){
  return(
    <div id="upcoming_estimates" className="">
          <h2>upcoming Estimates</h2>
          <p>This area is for upcoming estimates</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This is separate file, `EstimatesSent.js`

```
function EstimatesSent(){
  return(
    <div id="estimates_sent" className="">
        <h2>Sent Estimates</h2>
        <p>This area is for Sent Estimates</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

this shows few router changes, in `App.js`, import both `EstimatesSent` and `UpcomingEstimates`,

```
<Route path = '/estimates-home' component={Estimates} >
  <Route path="/UpcomingEstimates" component={(props) => ( <UpcomingEstimates /> )} />
  <Route path="/estimatesSent" component={(props) => ( <EstimatesSent /> )} />
</Route>
```

Comment: do i add this switch to app.js? it returns an error.

Comment: you can add in App or use nested routes

Comment: does not work , tabs just lying there

Comment: forget this, take above answer

Comment: Can you kindly show me the correct way to have it implemented , using the code i showed youin the question, I did exactly what you said and it is static. Not even moving

Comment: Please see Edits

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [selectedTab, set] = useState(1);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        Click to select tab!
        <div
          className={`tab ${selectedTab === 1 && "selected"}`}
          onClick={() => set(1)}
        >
          Tab1
        </div>
        <div
          className={`tab ${selectedTab === 2 && "selected"}`}
          onClick={() => set(2)}
        >
          Tab2
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="content">Content for Tab {selectedTab}</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

See result here: https://75zpi.csb.app/

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/75zpi